# Does vue-google-login plugin work under localhost?

Tags: vuejs2, google-authentication

Does https://github.com/rmartide/vue-google-login plugin work under localhost ?
I need to support vuejs 2 app and trying to login locally under http://127.0.0.1:8000/
I got error opening google auth page:

```
Ошибка 400: invalid_request
Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
```

but in my app there is a code :

```
let client_id = "";
if (location.hostname == "127.0.0.1") {
    console.log('127.0.0.1 LACLHOST ASSIGNED::')

    // local developers site
    client_id =
        "XNNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // I create this client_id in google's console for localhost
}
if (location.hostname == "remote-dev-server") {
    client_id =
        "XXXNNNNXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
}
Vue.use(LoaderPlugin, {
    client_id: client_id
});
```

Looks like it works under remote-dev-server,

What have to look at for checks?

Thanks!